# Python Import Class With Same Name as Directory

Tags: python, import, importerror

Lets say I have the following python source file layout:

```
lib/foo.py
lib/foo/bar.py
```

and then in my source code:

```
from foo import gaz
```

I get an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named foo
```

How can I have a .py file and a directory with the same name so I can do the following:

```
 from foo import gaz
 from foo.bar import wakawaka
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder

Comment: @Moj not the same.  That post is about relative imports. The issue im trying to figure out is how to have a .py file with the same name as a directory *in the same directory* and then import from the .py

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The actual problem you are having, using a single import, is due to the [packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) having the precedence over modules:

> Note that when using `from package import item`, the item can be either
>   a submodule (or subpackage) of the package, or some other name defined
>   in the package, like a function, class or variable. The `import`
>   statement first tests whether the item is defined in the package; if
>   not, it assumes it is a module and attempts to load it. If it fails to
>   find it, an `ImportError` exception is raised.

Anyway I'd *strongly* suggest to rename the file or the directory since you **cannot** import more than one module with a given name. The problem occurs because each module/package object is stored into `sys.modules`, which is a simple `dict` and thus it cannot contain multiple equal keys.

In particular, assuming `foo.py` and the `foo` directory are in different directories(and if they aren't you still can't import `foo.py`), when doing:

```
from foo import gaz
```

It will load `foo.py` and put the module into `sys.modules`, then trying to do:

```
from foo.bar import wakaka
```

Will fail because the import tries to use the module `foo.py` instead of the package.

The opposite happens if you first import `foo.bar`; the imports will use the package instead of the module.

Comment: The only import statement I am trying to execute is `from foo import gaz` where the class `gaz` is defined in foo.py.  Are you saying it is not possible to have foo.py and foo/bar.py then import a function from foo.py?

Comment: @DavidWilliams I've updated. The error you are seeing is due to the import order, even though my first answer is still relevant when you are dealing with modules/packages with the same name.

Comment: I think actually we might be talking about slightly different things.  Try this:
`touch foo.py && mkdir foo && touch foo/__init__.py && touch foo/bar.py`  create a class called Foo in foo.py and Bar in bar.py.  Then try to import `$ python -c "from foo import Foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Foo`

Comment: @DavidWilliams The code in your comment simply confirms what I state in my answer. The `foo` package is loaded and then it cannot find the name `Foo`. The answer to your question is that you *cannot* have `foo.py` and `foo/__init__.py` in the same directory and have a working `import`.

Comment: Well, I understand, and accept.  Kinda seems like a wart on Python.  In *many* OO languages is common to have this file and directory setup for namespace purposes, but ok.

Comment: @DavidWilliams I think the problem is that python `import` is completely different the the "import" of most other languages. For example in Java & co. it's pretty easy to understand if the name is the name of a class(hence a file) or of a package(hence a directory), and so this problem doesn't exist. I believe this choice was made because trying "smarter" semanthics would create much more side effects(e.g. modules aren't singleton anymore, or packages must become completely different objects etc.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is not something you should do, but you can force Python to import specific file as a module using [imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html):

```
import imp

with open("foo.py") as source:
    foo = imp.load_module("foo", source, "./", ('', '', imp.PY_SOURCE))
```

now you can do:

```
gaz_instance = foo.gaz()
```

Comment: This works only assuming that the working directory is the same where `foo.py` is, but this may not be true, since the OP's `lib` directory could have been added to the `sys.path` in some way. To obtain the directory you should call `imp.find_module('foo')` and get extract the path to the file. I didn't add this to my answer because it is a big change in how `import` works and should only be used if required(e.g. dynamically loading a plug-in/extension at runtime).

Comment: `imp.find_module('foo')` will return the info for package in /foo/ directory (assuming both foo.py and /foo/ are in the same dir)