# Django - split views into separate files while maintaining views.py

Tags: django, django-views

Hopefully this is a simple noob question. I'm working on my first large(ish) Django project. The first engineer on the project was following the default Django code layout. As things have grown we've recently split out models into their own directory with one file per model.

It's time to start doing the same for views. However, I don't want/need to do it all in one go. I'd like to just start moving things out of the default `views.py` one by one as I work on them. However, I'm having difficulty getting `urls.py` to work with both a views directory and  `views.py`

Is this just going to cause a naming collision when I try to import 'views' in my `urls.py` file? Is the simple answer just to call "views" something else while I make the transition? Or just bite the bullet and do it all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer is yes, you have a python naming collision. See for example [Python Import Class With Same Name as Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245106/python-import-class-with-same-name-as-directory)

You don't need to do it all as once though -- you can simply rename / move your views.py file or your new views directory. Moving the new directory would likely be easiest, then you won't have change your existing url routes.

There's nothing special about views.py files, as long as your urls.py points to the appropriate function, you can place them anywhere, and call them anything.

Comment: Thanks, that was the confirmation I as looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating feature sub-directories within your app folder on your Django project. Then, simply import them from the new directory using the `app.views` namespace by using the `from ... import *` incantation. This will import any views without the module name prepended (e.g. what would normally be referenced by `app_name.views.feature_one.view_class` becomes `app_name.views.view_class` like you want). See below:

---

```
# app_name/views.py
from feature_one.views import *
from feature_two.views import *

# ... copy views from here
```

---

```
# new file: app_name/feature_one/views.py

# ... paste some views here
```

---

```
# new file: app_name/feature_two/views.py

# ... paste some other views here
```

---

```
# new file: app_name/feature_one/__init__.py

# ... this file can be blank. required for importing "feature_one" like a module
```

---

```
# new file: app_name/feature_two/__init__.py

# ... this file can be blank. required for importing "feature_two" like a module
```

---

Now, while your views will be spread across sub-directories, they are all imported with the same names into `app_name.views` so you can still reference the same names in `urls.py` despite having moved some views to other files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have divided models into their sub-apps, you can define urls specific to these sub-apps in the created sub directories and set up a url hierarchy. This is how your default `urls.py` will look like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... snip ...
    url(r'^comments/', include('your_website.comments.urls')),
    url(r'^community/', include('your_website.community.urls')),
    url(r'^contact/', include('your_website.contact.urls')),
    # ... snip ...
)
```

where comments, community and contact are your newly created sub-apps/sub-directories. More info on how the url dispatcher works, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)