# Module * has no attribute * using nosetests

Tags: python, attributeerror, nose

I do the task from "Python Learn Hard Way" book. It is about using tests with `nose`.
I have the function `scan_net` in `lexicon.py` file:

```
def scan_net(sentence):
    direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
    verb = ['go', 'kill', 'eat', 'breath']
    stop_words = ['the', 'in', 'off']
    nouns = ['bear', 'princess', 'frog']

    words = sentence.split()
    result = []
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i] in direction:
            result.append(('direction', words[i]))
        elif words[i] in verb:
            result.append(('verb', words[i]))
        elif words[i] in stop_words:
            result.append(('stop_words', words[i]))
        elif words[i] in nouns:
            result.append(('nouns', words[i]))
        #check for number and if it is go out of the loop using continue
        try:
            if(int(words[i])):
                result.append(('number', words[i]))
                continue
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            result.append(('error', words[i]))
    return result
```

And this is my tests file:

```
from nose.tools import *
import lexicon

def test_directions():
    result = lexicon.scan_net("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                        ('direction', 'south'),
                        ('direction', 'east')])
```

After I run `nosetests tests\lexicon_tests.py` command I get
`AttributeError:module 'lexicon' has no attribute 'scan_net'`.

What is wrong with my import? Why it does not see the function `scan_net`?

Comment: Do you also have a folder named "lexicon" in the same path? Anecdotally, you may find the [builtin `unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) and [`coverage.py`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/) (together) to be cleaner and friendlier than nose, which is [no longer developed](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Import Class With Same Name as Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245106/python-import-class-with-same-name-as-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a folder named `lexicon` in your path which is being preferred and should rename one or the other to make it clearer which should be imported.

You should still be able to import with `from lexicon import scan_net`, but generally having different names will make your life easier.

See [Python Import Class With Same Name as Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245106/python-import-class-with-same-name-as-directory)